# Rewrite ASP.Net MVC homepage to another IP address

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-8

I have been trying to rewrite my homepage to another ip address in my ASP.Net MVC application. I have installed URL Rewrite and Application Request Routing modules in IIS. I have set the rewrite in my web.config, when i change the action type to redirect it works perfectly, but once i change it back to rewrite it does not work at all.
I have changed the matching url to accept all requests, but still it does not work.

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <clear />
         <rule name="node" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="*" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="http://255.255.255.255/" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

It seems like rewriting process has some conflicts with routing. How could i make the priority of rewrite higher?

Comment: Rewrite is just that, rewriting the url so that your application can process it better. For example, `product.myserver.com/pepsi` can be rewriten as `myserver.com/product?name=pepsi` so your application has parameter `name` with value `pepsi`. It does not change redirect the request to the specified url and it does not change the url in the written on client's browser.

Comment: No, I might explain not clear enough, i expect to see the content of http://255.255.255.255/ while im in root of my website but it does not like that. simply it skip the process.

Comment: If you want to see the content of 255.255.255.255, then what you need is a redirect. Rewrite won't redirect the request to the specified url.

Comment: Rewrite will show the content of specified url to matching url without noticing the user about source url, if i change the matching element to any other url except home page it works perfectly

Comment: You're misunderstanding rewrite. It will show the content of the specified url within the SAME server and SAME application. It will not redirect the request to different application let alone different server. So if `app1` receives request on `server1.com` and IIS rewrite the request to `server2.com`, `server1.com` will not redirect the request to `server2.com`. `app1` on `server1.com` will still get the request

Comment: it is called reverse proxy, and its possible.

Comment: In fact, if i had any other web application except ASP.Net MVC, rewriting the homepage to another app from another server in IIS was easy. but in asp.net MVC i suppose the asp.net routing prevents the rewrite process somehow\

Comment: This is the official Microsoft documentation on rewrite. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rule_action Rewrite is not supposed to redirect. If you want to show the content from the specified rewrite url, then you need to handle that on your application. IIS does not do that.

Comment: Of course rewrite is not redirecting the page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to configure an [Application Request Routing Server Farm](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/define-and-configure-an-application-request-routing-server-farm) that will consist of only one server (you should specify an IP for this server). After that you need to configure a global URL rewrite rule as described [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing).

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of the URL Rewrite Module in the `<rewrite>` section is for internal URLs, and cannot rewrite domain or IP of the server:

> [IIS.NET:](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rewrite_Rules_Overview) A Rewrite action replaces the current URL string with a substitution
>   string. A substitution string must always specify the URL path (for
>   example, contoso/test/default.aspx).

What you asked is not an url rewrite, but a reverse proxy. If you have an access to IIS, you can try its [reverse proxy configuration](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing), or simply create an HttpHandler, similar to this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7135/Simple-HTTP-Reverse-Proxy-with-ASP-NET-and-IIS). Next option can be http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com

Comment: Thats what i am saying, if you configure the reverse proxy in IIS for asp.net mvc app, it does not work for the home page

Comment: You have rewrting, not a reverse proxy. `<action type="Rewrite"` stays for rewriting and does not accept urls with domains or IP ( `http://255.255.255.255/`) in it.

Comment: @Behzad, smirnov's answer is lexical correct. **A domain is a domain.** If you mixed domains on the same application, you could actually have different IP's resolve to the same site. This would be an implicitly resolved redirect. **And that would be a configuration hack  and would not be a programming question.** So the answer is completely correct while remaining on topic.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich would you please look when you are using reverse proxy what code will be generated in iis ? what i mentioned in my question is what iis generated for a reverse proxy.  I am sure you did not read my question properly, as i said if i change my project to something except asp.net MVC project it works perfectly.

Comment: @Behzad, I can re-read and try to see if I missed something. Side point, did you down-vote 2 of my answers? I have 2 down-votes on my top voted answers and same time you made 2 downvotes this morning...

Comment: @Behzad, I've had no response as to why you downvoted my top voted answers, so I have to assume it was revenge for my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

Would there be config inheritance happening?
If so, you can wrap the section you want with <location> to disable inheritence from parent app...

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```